# $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m$ is a permutation of $1,2,\ldots,m$ and $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m$ be integer and $m>1$ and odd.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

$x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m$ is a permutation of $1,2,\ldots,m$ and $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m$ be integer and $m>1$ and $m$ is odd. Now, $f(x)$ be defined as $f(x)=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{m} n_ix_j$. If $a,b$ are distinct permutations, then prove that there exists $a,b$ such that $f(a)\equiv f(b)\mod m!$

My attempt:
I thought of using PHP and to show that two equal remainders exist. There are $m!$ available $f(x)$ as there are $m!$ ways of re-arranging $1,2,\ldots,m$ and there are $m!$ remainders available namely $0,1,\ldots,m!-1$.

Now, I cannot use PHP here as there are equal number of holes as that of pigeons. But, is there some remainders that do not occur, because it has to be true otherwise we will get a contradiction, but I cannot think of it and neither prove it. Please help.

Comment: $$\sum_{i,j=1}^mn_ix_j =\left(\sum_{i=1}^mn_i\right) \left(\sum_{j=1}^mx_j\right)$$ which is the same for all permutations. Did you mean $$\sum_{i=1}^mn_ix_i$$

Comment: @robjohn no, the suffix of $n$ and $x$ need not be same, the positions of $n_i$'s are fixed but the $x_i$'s change their positions.

Comment: Yes, I understand that for two different permutations, the order of the $x_j$ will change, but the way you have it written, there are $m^2$ summands and the sum does not change with any permutation.

Comment: @robjohn yes, I am sorry, but the thing is so complicated I could not properly represent it...